# How to build the jar artifact for a Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, jar

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5 and I've used Spring Initializr to setup a Spring Boot project. Everything works fine and I can run and test my project in the IDE.

Right now, when I want to build the jar file, I run the following command from command prompt:

```
$ mvn package
```

where my `pom.xml` is located and the jar file is created perfectly (with a caveat that I'm going to tell you about it later). The thing is, I'm looking for a way to do the same from within the IDE.

So far I've tried to create a new jar artifact in Project Structure window (Alt+Ctrl+Shift+s) and include the project's output while for the maven dependencies I use `Extract into Output Root`. This way, the artifact can be built and run but there are lots of error messages given out and some of the functionalities are not working.

Does anyone know how to build a jar file for Spring Boot project from within IntelliJ IDEA?

The reason why I need to build my jar file in IDE is that my project is composed of several maven projects and I've imported them all as modules into one project. When I run the main module in the IDE, IntelliJ IDEA is smart enough to consider the module as the dependencies for the main one. But when I use the command prompt `mvn`, this is not happening (which is totally understandable since maven only knows of main project and not the rest). If only I can build from within the IDE..

To clarify my situation better, I've got a "Main" project and a "Library" which of course Library is a dependency of Main. Since I don't have maven repository (and at this point, I'm not looking for one), the only way I know of to make it possible for the maven to compile my code is to name Library in Main's pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

which as far as I know is highly discouraged. This is in the case that if I name the Library as an ordinary dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

since a neighboring module (Library) outputs the exact same artifact, IntelliJ IDEA is capable of matching the dependency with that module and compile the code. But in case of `mvn`, since there's no module involved, this can not be done and the dependency is not satisfied. In other words, I can only config my environment to work with `mvn` or IntelliJ IDEA, but not both!

Comment: Why not make the other modules dependencies in your maven config?

Comment: I'll explain in the question

Answer (score 8):

Go to the project root folder such as springbootdemo and run below commands:

1. `mvnw clean package` (This will create the target folder and generate the jar inside it)
2. `mvnw spring-boot:run` (This will run the spring boot application). 
   In my case application name is `springbootdemo` and its location is `C:\Users\springbootdemo` and I ran both commands at this location.

Comment: running ```./mvnw clean package``` solved the issue

Comment: For my spring-boot application this will make .war file. How to build .jar file so I can run my RESTful app with 'java -jar app.jar' on my Ubuntu server?

Comment: Ok, now I see that `java -jar myApp.war` also works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From within IDEA, you can go in the tool window "Maven Project", and here double click on Package.

Comment: If you can't find `Maven Project`, use `Ctrl + E` to search for it.